# Select zipcode and drop into new column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql table which contains a column with a lot of information. From this column I only need the zip code. I can select the rows that contain a zip code with:

```
SELECT *
FROM Flow
Where Title LIKE '% [0-9] [0-9] [0-9] [0-9] [A-Z] [A-Z]%'
```

Example data:

```
B2 (Use Ambu: b-ride care) 13401 Rit 24530 Amsterdam Linnaeusstraat 1093EN Basic team Oost-Watergraafsmeer
B2 Outpatient clinic Urology Route 23 Wagnerlaan Arnhem 6815AD 17143
B2 (Use Ambu: b-ride care) 13401 Rit 24531 Amsterdam Vrolikstraat 1092TX
B2 Outpatient clinic Urology Route 23 Wagnerlaan Arnhem 6815AD 17143
A2 Weth R A Wieggersstraat Giesbeek 6987BD 17145
```

But now I just want to put the postcode from these rows in another column with the name zip code.

The result:

```
ZipCode
1093EN
6815AD
1092TX
6815AD
6987BD
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Add some more sample table data, and also specify the expected result. (Still formatted text. No images, please.)

Comment: It is a rss feed which is taken to a SQL server via Microsoft Flow

Comment: Hey, not as a comment. Edit the question instead.

Comment: it seems like it'd be easiest to simply parse the data into columns (as there appears to be a general consistency) moving from the RSS to the SQL table.  any way to parse based on tabs or spaces (as is possible using the import feature in SSMS)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PATINDEX` can find the position of such pattern with the same syntax as a `LIKE`.

And once you have the position a SUBSTRING can get it.

```
SELECT *, 
 SUBSTRING(Title, PATINDEX('%[^0-9A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z][^0-9A-Z]%', Title+' ')+1, 6) AS ZipCode
FROM Flow
WHERE Title+' ' LIKE '%[^0-9A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z][^0-9A-Z]%'
```

Without the `WHERE` clause that filters the records that have a ZipCode, the `PATINDEX` would return 0 when there's no ZipCode.
Then to avoid that the `SUBSTRING` would still return something from string without it, it's best to wrap it in a `CASE`.

```
SELECT *, 
(CASE
 WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z][^0-9A-Z]%', Title+' ') > 0
  THEN SUBSTRING(Title, PATINDEX('%[^0-9A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z][^0-9A-Z]%', Title+' ')+1, 6) 
  END) AS ZipCode
FROM Flow
```

Extra:

About the other table.
Here is an example snippet using temp tables to demonstrate:

```
-- Using a temporary table for the example
CREATE TABLE #Flow (
  Id int primary key identity(1,1) not null,
  Col1 VARCHAR(8) not null,
  Title NVARCHAR(100) not null,
  ZipCode VARCHAR(6)
);

-- Sample data
INSERT INTO #Flow (Col1, Title) VALUES
('B2X1', N'B2 (Use Ambu: b-ride care) 13401 Rit 24531 Amsterdam Vrolikstraat 1092TX'),
('B2X2', N'B2 Outpatient clinic Urology Route 23 Wagnerlaan Arnhem 6815AD 17143'),
('A2Y1', N'A2 Weth R A Wieggersstraat Giesbeek 6987BD 17145');

 CREATE TABLE #OtherTable (
  Id int primary key identity(1,1) not null,
  OtherCol1 VARCHAR(8) not null,
  FlowId INT,
  ZipCode VARCHAR(6)
);

-- update the ZipCode in the origin table
UPDATE  #Flow
SET ZipCode = SUBSTRING(Title, PATINDEX('%[^0-9A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z][^0-9A-Z]%', Title+' ')+1, 6) 
WHERE ZipCode IS NULL
   AND PATINDEX('%[^0-9A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z][^0-9A-Z]%', Title+' ') > 0;

SELECT * FROM  #Flow;

INSERT INTO #OtherTable (OtherCol1, FlowId, ZipCode)
SELECT f.Col1, f.Id, f.ZipCode
FROM #Flow f
ORDER BY f.Col1 DESC, f.Id ASC;

SELECT * FROM  #OtherTable;
```

A test on rextester [here](https://rextester.com/MOMAS17612)

Comment: Thx, and you probably noticed the added `[^0-9A-Z]`. that just to assure the substring is surrounded by characters that are NOT alphabetic or digits.

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me how I can ensure that all columns including the new zip code column go to another table?

Comment: To another table.  You want to [INSERT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) from a SELECT as new records? Or [UPDATE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) a ZipCode column for existing records? Or both and upsert via a [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql)?  Choices, choices.

Comment: I think 2 options. Option 1: Get the zipcode column standard in the same table or transport all of the columns to a new table. I need the table for power bi where i can use the ZipCode column.

Comment: @MJHHBis Check out the extra.  It's just an example because I don't know your tables.  But you should be able to work out something from that.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative :

```
SELECT *, 
 SUBSTRING(yazi, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z]%', yazi), 6) AS ZipCode
FROM #Onder
```